# does a linear differential equation have a well defined initial value problem if a term diverges at initial 'time'?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have a differential equation like the following:

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+t^2x=0$$

And I've to put initial conditions at $t=-\infty$. Now the $t^2$ bit seems to diverge at $t=-\infty$. Is that a problem? More generally can I put initial conditions at any time t if one or more of the coefficients of the equation diverges at t?

My feeling is that we need to find the solutions (parabolic cylindrical functions in this case apparently) and if they are well behaved at the initial time then there is no problem. Is that correct?

Note: I am a physicist, so please keep your answers a bit simple :)

Edit: In this paper one finds an example of such an equation being applied http://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.2496v1.pdf (equation 59-62).

Comment: It doesn't always make sense to put an initial condition at infinity. A fairly common situation in second order linear ODEs is that you have two independent solutions which have singularities in different locations, such as one at zero and the other at infinity. You can then impose the condition that there is actually no singularity at infinity, in which case the coefficient of the solution with a singularity at infinity must be zero.

Comment: I understand. But my question is about the singularity in the coefficient rather than in the solution. Is a singularity in the coefficient a problem, if the solution doesn't diverge itself? In my case the physics of the problem demands that I put initial conditions at minus infinity.

Comment: There is almost certainly a badly behaved solution when the coefficient behaves badly like that. As for the initial conditions, you could try to reconcile that by putting initial conditions at $t=t_0$ and sending $t_0 \to -\infty$, but with the singularity in the coefficient I have my doubts that the result will converge (unless the structure I described in my previous comment is in fact present).

Comment: You might consider the following physically motivated calculation: $x'' x'+t^2 x x'=0 \Rightarrow x'(t)^2/2-x'(t_0)^2/2+\int_{t_0}^t s^2 x(s) x'(s) ds = 0$. Integrate by parts to get $x'(t)^2/2 - x'(t_0)^2/2 + t^2 x(t)^2/2 - t_0^2 x(t_0)^2/2 - \int_{t_0}^t s x(s)^2 ds = 0$. In other words the change in the "energy" $x'(t)^2/2+t^2 x(t)^2/2$ is $\int_{t_0}^t s x(s)^2 ds$. There will need to be considerable decay in $x$ at $-\infty$ in order for this to converge as $t_0 \to -\infty$. My guess is then that your ICs include $x(-\infty)=0$?

Comment: Yes, one would expect the energy to diverge. If one plots the 'potential well' it blows up at $-\infty$. So at any finite time the energy should indeed be infinite. That may not necessarily conflict with the physics - please see the reference I added above.

Comment: These are plots of the solutions: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot++ParabolicCylinderD%5B-0.5,+(1%2BI)x%5D,++x%3D-30+to+30

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot++ParabolicCylinderD%5B-0.5,+(-1%2BI)x%5D,++x%3D-30+to+30

They don't look like they're approaching zero.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+t^2x=0$$
Changing $t$ to $-t$ doesn't change $x(t)$. Hense $x(t)$ is an even function.

The general solution can be expressed in terms of particular parabolic cylinder functions. But the variable of those functions are on the complex range, which leads to more complicated interpretation.

The ODE is also a generalized form of Bessel ODE. The general solution can be expressed in terms of particular Bessel functions (related to the above parabolic cylinder functions. But doesn't matter, the Bessel form of solution can be derived directly) :

$$x(t)=c_1\sqrt{|t|}J_{1/4}\left(\frac{t^2}{2}\right)+c_2\sqrt{|t|}J_{-1/4}\left(\frac{t^2}{2}\right)$$
The function $x(t)$ is real and finite for all real $x$, insofar the coefficients $c_1$ and $c_2$ are real.

$t\to \pm\infty \quad x(t)\to 0$ , asmptotically: 
$\sqrt{|t|}J_{\pm 1/4}\left(\frac{t^2}{2}\right) \sim \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sin\left(\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{\pi}{8} \right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{|t|}}$

$t=0 \quad \begin{cases}
\sqrt{|t|}J_{-1/4}\left(\frac{t^2}{2}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\Gamma(\frac{3}{4})} \quad \text{; derivative}=0\\
\sqrt{|t|}J_{1/4}\left(\frac{t^2}{2}\right) =0 \quad \text{; discontinuous derivative}
\end{cases}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you're saying that I cannot put initial conditions at minus infinity, because the solution goes to 0 there?  Also both solutions have the same asymptotic form?

Comment: That isn't exactly my thinking. What I wrote is a pure mathematical consequence of the form of a given equation. But, is this equation really representative of all the physical situation ?. If the Mathematician doesn't agree with the Physician, most probably, there is a little bit of something missing in the model which causes the discrepancy.

Comment: But in this specific case, clearly we cannot put initial conditions at minus infinity? If both independent solutions vanish at minus infinity, it would make no sense to put initial conditions there, surely?

Comment: Yes, in this specific case.